# Export XML data stored in Table’s columns to xml files

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have to export XML data stored in Table’s cell to xml file.

I tried running below query

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
GO

-- Save XML records to a file:
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE @sqlStr VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(1000)

SET @fileName = 'D:\SQL_Queries\PersonAdditionalContactInfo.xml'
SET @sqlStr = 'select TOP 1 AdditionalContactInfo from AdventureWorks2012.Person.Person where AdditionalContactInfo IS NOT NULL'

SET @sqlCmd = 'bcp "' + @sqlStr + '" queryout ' + @fileName + ' -w -T'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd
```

as suggested at https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2015/04/13/export-xml-column-data-to-a-file-xml/

After running this query I am getting below  output to grid

> usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
>   [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]   [-F
>   firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]   [-n
>   native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character
>   type]   [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted
>   identifier]   [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r
>   row terminator]   [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]
>   [-a packetsize]   [-S server name]          [-U username]
>   [-P password]   [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R
>   regional enable]   [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
>   [-h "load hints"]         [-x generate xml format file] NULL

But there no file created at location 'D:\SQL_Queries\'

Comment: Maybe you are looking on the wrong `D:\`, SQL Server is running in its own context. If this is not your local machine your `D:\` might be somewhere else...

Comment: See webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx.

Comment: Hi, is this still open? Do you need further help? If this issue is solved, it would be kind to tick the acceptance check below vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. As you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me **(filepath is in the context of your SQL Server!!!)**:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tmpTest(AdditionalContactInfo XML);
INSERT INTO dbo.tmpTest(AdditionalContactInfo) SELECT '<root><a>SomeTest</a></root>';

DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(50)='"C:\ExisitingDirectory\PersonAdditionalContactInfo.xml"';
--attention: Change the table's name!
DECLARE @sqlStr VARCHAR(1000)='select TOP 1 AdditionalContactInfo from master.dbo.tmpTest where AdditionalContactInfo IS NOT NULL';
--attention: Change the server's name
DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(1000) = 'bcp "' + @sqlStr + '" queryout ' + @fileName + ' -S TheServer -c -w -T';

EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.tmpTest;
```